# Define a pointer as a method of a class?

Tags: python, c, cython

I am trying to speed up my cython code. I came across [this link](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/08/memoryview-benchmarks/) where the author has described how using **pointers** instead of **numpy arrays** can improve the speed of cython codes. In my **cosmology** class the bottleneck is **Da** function. I am not very familiar with pointers in **C**, I would appreciate if somebody give me an idea:

Is it possible to define a method of a class as a pointer for instance in my case convert `np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] Da`  to something like `double* Da`?

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
import copy
cdef extern from "gsl/gsl_math.h":
    ctypedef struct gsl_function:
        double (* function) (double x, void * params)
        void * params

cdef extern from "gsl/gsl_integration.h":
    ctypedef struct gsl_integration_workspace
    gsl_integration_workspace *  gsl_integration_workspace_alloc(size_t n)
    void  gsl_integration_workspace_free(gsl_integration_workspace * w)
    int  gsl_integration_qags(const gsl_function * f, double a, double b, double epsabs, double epsrel, size_t limit, gsl_integration_workspace * workspace, double *result, double *abserr)


cdef double func_callback(double x, void* params): 
     return (<cosmology>params).__angKernel(x) 

cdef class cosmology(object):
    cdef public double omega_m, omega_l, h, w, omega_r, G, v_c
    cdef object omega_c
    def __init__(self,double omega_m = 0.3, double omega_l = 0.7, double h = 0.7, double w = -1, double omega_r = 0., double G = std_G):

        self.omega_m = omega_m
        self.omega_l = omega_l
        self.omega_r = omega_r
        self.omega_c = (1. - omega_m - omega_l)
        self.h = h
        self.w = w
        self.G = G
        self.v_c = v_c

    def __copy__(self):

        return cosmology(omega_m = self.omega_m, omega_l = self.omega_l, h = self.h, w = self.w, omega_r = self.omega_r, G = self.G)

    property H0:
       def __get__(self):
           return 100*self.h  #km/s/MPC

    cpdef double a(self, double z):
        return 1./(1.+z)

    cpdef double E(self, double a):
        return (self.omega_r*a**(-4) + self.omega_m*a**(-3) + self.omega_c*a**(-2) + self.omega_l)**0.5

    @cython.boundscheck(False)
    @cython.wraparound(False)
    @cython.nonecheck(False)
    cdef double __angKernel(self, double x):
         """Integration kernel for angular diameter distance computation.
         """
         return self.E(x**-1)**-1

    @cython.boundscheck(False)
    @cython.wraparound(False)
    @cython.nonecheck(False)
    cpdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] Da(self, np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] z, double z_ref=0):
          cdef gsl_integration_workspace* w =gsl_integration_workspace_alloc(1000)

          cdef gsl_function F
          F.function = &func_callback
          F.params = <void*>self

          cdef double result = 3, error = 5
          cdef double err, rk, zs, omc
          omc=self.omega_c
          cdef np.ndarray[double,ndim=1] d = np.ones_like(z, dtype=np.float64, order='C')
          cdef int i, num
          num = len(z)
          for i in range(num):
              zs=z[i]
              if zs < 0:
                 raise ValueError("Redshift z must not be negative")
              if zs < z_ref:
                 raise ValueError("Redshift z must not be smaller than the reference redshift")
              gsl_integration_qags(&F, z_ref+1, zs+1, 0, 1e-7, 1000, w, &result, &error)
              d[i], err = result, error 
              # check for curvature
              rk = (fabs(omc))**0.5
              if (rk*d[i] > 0.01):
                 if omc > 0:
                    d[i] = sinh(rk*d[i])/rk
                 if omc < 0:
                    d[i] = sin(rk*d[i])/rk

          gsl_integration_workspace_free(w) 
          return d/(1.+z)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding a @cython.cdivision(True) decorator as well (won't raise a python exception on divide by 0). It doesn't answer your question, but it may well speed things up a bit. Personally, I doubt using double* will make that much difference.

Comment: @DavidW I need to improve the speed of my code by 10 times and I don't know how. Do you have any particular reason why using pointers won't help to speed up the code?

Comment: You can look at the C code that Cython generates (use `cython -a <filename>` and look at the html file it makes - sorry if you already know that). If you look at the way Cython handles numpy arrays like yours it's pretty close to just using pointers anyway. The link you give at the start of your answer is more about the cost of creating views of arrays at the function call (i.e. taking the first column of a 2D array).

Comment: While there's probably tricks you can use to improve your function it's probably not too far off optimised right now, so I'd be genuinely surprised if you could get 10x improvement. I've been surprised before though. I'd try the `@cython.cdivision(True)` I suggested before, remove the exceptions if you can, and specify the input argument `z` as `np.ndarray[double, ndim=1,mode="c"]` (that promises the data is packed as a 1D array), but that's really all I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since I developed in cython, but if memory serves me I believe you could declare the function as follows:

ctypedef double* ( * Da)(double* z, double z_ref, int length)

This function will return an array of type double and allow you to pass an array of doubles in as z.  This is a function pointer, so maybe not quite what you want.

ctypedef double* Da(double* z, double z_ref, int length)

this will accomplish same thing but as a regular function, not just a function pointer.  Difference between function and function pointer is you have to assign a function pointer a function to point to.

Comment: can I attribute an array to the output of the second definition?

Comment: Yep!  It is exactly the same as the first only you declare it as a normal function.  I apologize, I probably shouldn't have thrown in the part about function pointers as it can be very confusing.  It may be helpful to you down the road as the tutorial you referenced uses them, but they are not essential to what you are wanting to accomplish.  The second declaration I listed will work just fine and is a normal function declaration that accepts an array of type double and a double as arguments and will return an array of type double.

Comment: So far you have mentioned how I can define a function pointer but when I want to re-write my method how should be define?

Comment: cpdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] Da(self, np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] z, double z_ref=0):

becomes

ctypedef double* Da(double* z, double z_ref)

Comment: if you look at the site I have addressed it mentioned using numpy array reduces the speed of code. I want to avoid using it as much as possible.

Comment: Right, which is why if you read my answer above, I have given you two options to rewrite the function without using it at all :)  Use this as the function declaration: ctypedef double* Da(double* z, double z_ref) and you can pass in c arrays of type double and return one.

Comment: shouldn't it be like `ctypedef double* ( * Da)(double* z, double z_ref, int N)` where the last *integer* define the length of the array?

Comment: If *Da* is a method of cosmology class how the pointer of the function should be defined because I need to call it in another class.

Comment: My answer already has the definition for the function pointer in it.  To avoid a huge string of conversation here, it might be best for you to walk through a tutorial on pointers and function pointers in c.  They are nothing new, magical, or special.  They are simply a valuable tool to add to your programming skill set.  I would highly recommend you understand them better before you attempt to use them.  There are many good tutorials available and Google is your friend!